# Get results from joined tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my laravel app I track lesson enrollment and active subscriptions in different tables.

A lesson is defined by lesson_types table which has columns like this:

```
lesson_types
id | name | sub_plan
```

Enrollemnts are defined in enrolls table with columns like this:

```
enrolls
id | user_id | lesson_type_id
```

and my subscriptions table has columns like this:

```
subscriptions
id | name | sub_plan | user_id
```

Tables are connect like this:

- enrolls has 'lesson_type_id' which is 'id' of lesson_types table
- sub_plan column in lesson_types is the same as sub_plan in subscriptions

Sample database data in tables:

```
ennrolls
id  user_id lesson_type_id
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   2       1

lesson_types
id  name        sub_plan
1   Lesson 1    plan_1337
2   Lesson 2    plan_1338
3   Lesson 3    plan_1339

subscriptions
id  name    sub_plan    user_id
1   Sub 1   plan_1337   1
```

I tried to get all enrollments like this:

```
$enrolled = DB::table('enrolls')->where('user_id', $userId)
                ->leftJoin('lesson_types', 'id', '=', 'lesson_type_id')
                ->select('name');
```

But I need to get them without subscriptions...

What i want to achieve is:

1. Get all 'lesson_types' names where user is subscribed
2. Get all 'lesson_types' names where user has enrolled but not subscribed
3. Get all 'lesson_types' where user is not enrolled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Achieve the above scenario using Laravel Eloquent. Laravel has facilitated a lot of more in-built ORM methods. So We don't need to write manual SQL codes. Don't reinvent the wheel

Enrolls Model

```
namespace App;


use App\User;
use App\LessonType;
use App\Subscription;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * 
 */
class Enroll extends Model
{
    

    public function lessonType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(LessonType::class);
    }


    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

}
```

Lesson Types Model

```
namespace App;

use App\Enroll;
use App\Subscription;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * 
 */
class LessonType extends Model
{
    

    public function enrolls()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Enroll::class);
    }


    public function subscription()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subscription::class, 'sub_plan','sub_plan');
    }

    

}
```

Subscriptions Model

```
namespace App;


use App\User;
use App\LessonType;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * 
 */
class Subscription extends Model
{
    

    public function lessonType()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LessonType::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

In Constroller or Repository

```
LessonType::select('name')->has('subscription.user');
LessonType::select('name')->doesntHave('subscription.user');
LessonType::select('name')->doesntHave('enrolls.users');
```

FYI :
[Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

Follow this approaches. Take it as Best Practice